# Mongodb is not showing the result in browser but showing in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am running below code as my router:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
// connect with our model
let ByProduct = require('../models/Byproduct')
router.get('/',(req,res,next)=>{
    ByProduct.find().then((err,ProductList)=>{
        if(err)
        {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        else
        {
            //console.log("Hello world");
            res.render('Byproduct', {title: 'Product List', productList: ProductList})
        }
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Router is showing me the result in console but not in browser, its not rendering my 'Byproduct' page. If I only use find with old version and ignore then, then it show me error that find no more working with call backs, any help will be appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code to use `async/await` pattern with `try/catch` for better error handling like so:

```js
router.get('/', async (req,res,next)=>{ //< Mark function as async
   try{
      const productList = await ByProduct.find(); //< Use of await keyword
      res.render('Byproduct', {
         title: 'Product List', 
         productList: productList
      });
   }catch(err){
      console.error(err);
      //Handle error
      res.render('Byproduct', {
         error: 'Error on server'
      });
   }
});
```

If your view file `Byproduct` is still not showing in the browser then your problem my be with your view engine. If that's the case then please post your ejs/handlebars/pug or whatever template package you are using for debugging help.